# Excel VBA Check if pivot field should be formatted as a number or a percentage

Tags: excel, pivot-table, percentage, vba

I don't know if this is possible but I am trying to design a macro that adds all pivot fields into the values section of a pivot table as either numbers or percentages.

Here is what I have so far:

```
If MsgBox("Do you want to add all pivot table fields as values?", vbOKCancel + vbQuestion, "Accept/Reject") = vbCancel Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pivotTableName As String

On Error Resume Next
Set pt = ActiveCell.PivotTable

If pt Is Nothing Then
    pivotTableName = InputBox("Enter the pivot table name.")
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pivotTableName)
End If

For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
    pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields(pf.Name), pf.Name & " ", xlSum
    pt.PivotFields(pf.Name & " ").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
Next pf
```

But next I'd like to add an if statement to see whether or not the field should be formatted as a percentage instead.
My ideas were:

1. Check a single record value in a field to see if it is less than 100% (or 1) (this would be ideal in 95% of situations I'm in)
2. Check that the sum of a field is less than an arbitrary number such as <100 (not perfect)
3. Check if the name of the field has % in it (what I'll probably have to go with)

   For Each fld in pt.PivotFields

   If InStr(fld.Value, "%") Then

   Next
4. Check if the field is a calculated field (not perfect)

   For Each fld in pt.PivotFields

   If fld.IsCalculated Then

   Next

Are the first two possible? Does anyone have better ideas?

Thanks!

P.S.
Another thing I was interest in doing is to check if the field contains text or maybe if the field cannot be summed.

Comment: until someone gives better answer, you can look into looping through the items of the PivotField https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820762.aspx (maybe pivotTable1.ColumnFields(1).ChildItems(1).Value)

Comment: Thanks for that, I think I have an idea, I'll try sum the field if error then it must be text otherwise after adding the summed field to the pivot table check its value then format it.

Comment: Sum ignores text values, but you might find other function that doesn't. I was thinking going through the pivotField values one by one to check and summing them

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing if anyone is interested:

Sub AutoAddFields()

```
If MsgBox("Do you want to add all pivot table fields as values?", vbOKCancel + vbQuestion, "Accept/Reject") = vbCancel Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pivotTableName As String

On Error Resume Next
Set pt = ActiveCell.PivotTable

If pt Is Nothing Then
    pivotTableName = InputBox("Enter the pivot table name.")
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pivotTableName)
End If

For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
    If InStr(pf.Value, "%") > 0 Then
        pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields(pf.Name), pf.Name & " ", xlSum
        pt.PivotFields(pf.Name & " ").NumberFormat = "0.0%"
    Else
        If pf.IsCalculated Then
            If InStr(pf.Formula, "/") > 0 Then
                pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields(pf.Name), pf.Name & " ", xlSum
                pt.PivotFields(pf.Name & " ").NumberFormat = "0.0%"
            Else
                pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields(pf.Name), pf.Name & " ", xlSum
                pt.PivotFields(pf.Name & " ").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
            End If
        Else
            pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields(pf.Name), pf.Name & " ", xlSum
            pt.PivotFields(pf.Name & " ").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        End If
    End If
Next pf

For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
    If (pt.GetPivotData(pf.Value & " ") = 0) Then
        pt.PivotFields(pf.Value & " ").Orientation = xlHidden
    End If
Next pf
```

End Sub